# Android: What make my application crash?

Tags: java, android, crash, report, nullpointerexception

I have been receiving a few errors a day and I am not sure what is going on.

If more information is needed, please let me know.

I probably didn't give enough information for anything.

Here is the error I get in my Developer Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.Calculator.SalesTaxCalculator/com.Calculator.SalesTaxCalculator.Calculator}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3199)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3380)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1049)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4369)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:846)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2920)
at com.Calculator.SalesTaxCalculator.BillingHelper.stopService(BillingHelper.java:265)
at com.Calculator.SalesTaxCalculator.Calculator.onDestroy(Calculator.java:302)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3181)
... 12 more
```

**Line 302**

```
protected void onDestroy() {
```

**From Line 301 and Beyond (This is the last set of code on that page.)**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    BillingHelper.stopService();
    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

**StopService Method in BillingHelper**

```
public static void stopService(){
                mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, BillingService.class));
                mService = null;
                mContext = null;
                mCompletedHandler = null;
                Log.i(TAG, "Stopping Service");
        }
}
```

Someone put in one of the crash report comments that the app does not even open. Some more information is that it uses shared Preferences to save numbers in the calculator. Also has a donation button which uses the in-app billing service.

Comment: Calculator.java:302 post this line also.

Comment: The minimum I supose what you should paste is detroy code from all your activites. And calculator code. Because it looks that there is and error.

Comment: `BillingHelper.stopService()` might contain error as well

Comment: please provide the sample code of SalesTaxCalculator.java and Calculator.java file.

Comment: Added more info, please check it out.

Comment: Might need the onCreate method too if its a FC

Comment: FC = Force Close. It appears as a window on your screen and prompts that the process of your app is crashed

Comment: I know what Force Close was, just didn't know the abbreviation. lol

Answer (score 2):

change it to call super.onDestroy(); first and then other stuff, for e.g:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    BillingHelper.stopService();
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to test to see if this would fix the issue? I have no idea what that crash is about or how to remake it, I only have 16 people out of over 15,000 with that issue.

Comment: Every device that I have tested my app on works with the app. This issue started when I added Billing to my app.

Comment: whats in the StopService method of BillingHelper?

Comment: is it the same context you used to start the service? Did you use application level context or Activity level context to start the service? in either case, you should use the same context to start/stop your service. and dont set your context to null if its application's context

Comment: is it the same context you used to start the service? Did you use application level context or Activity level context to start the service? in either case, you should use the same context to start/stop your service. and dont set your context to null if its application's context

Comment: A little confused on what you are explaining. Could you be a little more detailed please?